# Why is React-app state not re-rendering here? How to get state to update in time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect

I am trying to figure out how this works.

I have a 'pageCounter' variable for keeping track of the current page (updates upon prev/next button click) and when it updates I want to change the Title of the Option Cards to the new page data.

When I click the next button, it does not render unless I click it twice and the console log says it hasn't been updated yet. But when I click my 'log' button after hitting next it says it has updated?

I have done my research and assumed this is due to the async nature of the 'setState' function. However, I am not sure how to fix this?

I tried putting updateTitles function within the `useEffect` hook but get an error no matter if I copy the contents of the function into it, or call the function within the hook.

What am I missing?

The error I get when putting the contents of the `updateTitles` in `useEffect` is:

> Maximum Update Depth Exceeded.

Here is the component code: [(code sandbox here)](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-austin-vs5nw)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Options() {
  // Component States
  const [pageCounter, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [optionTitles, setOptionTitles] = useState({
    Option1: "End of Lease Clean",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  });
  //Component Variables
  const pageOneTitles = {
    Option1: "End of Lease Clean",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  };
  const pageTwoTitles = {
    Option1: "Blah1",
    Option2: "Blah12",
    Option3: "Blah13"
  };
  const pageThreeTitles = {
    Option1: "MrMagoo",
    Option2: "Nins",
    Option3: "Pottao"
  };

  function updateTitles() {
    switch (pageCounter) {
      case 1:
        setOptionTitles(pageOneTitles);
        break;
      case 2:
        setOptionTitles(pageTwoTitles);
        break;
      case 3:
        setOptionTitles(pageThreeTitles);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default");
        break;
    }
  }

  function nextPage() {
    if (pageCounter < 3) {
      setPage(pageCounter + 1);
      updateTitles();
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function prevPage() {
    if (pageCounter > 1) {
      setPage(pageCounter - 1);
      updateTitles();
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function printLog() {
    console.log(pageCounter);
  }

  return (
    <div id="options">
      <button onClick={prevPage} id="next">
        Back
      </button>
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option1} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option2} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option3} />
      <p>{}</p>
      <button onClick={nextPage} id="next">
        Next
      </button>
      <button onClick={printLog} id="next">
        log
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
function CardOption(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Options;
```

Here is the code for when I try to use the hook useEffect instead, but I get an error saying "Maximum Update Depth Exceeded".

```
        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Options() {
  // Component States
  const [pageCounter, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [optionTitles, setOptionTitles] = useState({
    Option1: "Page 1.11",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  });
  //Component Variables
  const pageOneTitles = {
    Option1: "Page 1.1",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  };
  const pageTwoTitles = {
    Option1: "Page 2.1",
    Option2: "Blah12",
    Option3: "Blah13"
  };
  const pageThreeTitles = {
    Option1: "Page 3.1",
    Option2: "Nins",
    Option3: "Pottao"
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (pageCounter) {
      case 1:
        setOptionTitles(pageOneTitles);
        break;
      case 2:
        setOptionTitles(pageTwoTitles);
        break;
      case 3:
        setOptionTitles(pageThreeTitles);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default");
        break;
    }
  }, [pageCounter, pageOneTitles, pageTwoTitles, pageThreeTitles]);

  function nextPage() {
    if (pageCounter < 3) {
      setPage(pageCounter + 1);
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function prevPage() {
    if (pageCounter > 1) {
      setPage(pageCounter - 1);
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function printLog() {
    console.log(pageCounter);
  }

  return (
    <div id="options">
      <button onClick={prevPage} id="next">
        Back
      </button>
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option1} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option2} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option3} />
      <p>{pageCounter}</p>
      <button onClick={nextPage} id="next">
        Next
      </button>
      <button onClick={printLog} id="next">
        log
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
function CardOption(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Options;
```

Here is the code sandbox for the useEffect hook : https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-panini-mkdzh

Comment: can you add a codesandbox with your code?

Comment: Added the sandbox to the original post too:  https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-panini-mkdzh

Comment: here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-event-pointers-x9yho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` runs for every state update. Make sure to set its deps like

```
useEffect(()=> {
   // do stuff with pagecounter , which is updated count

},[pageCount])
```

If you wanna run it only once when mounted

```
useEffect(()=> {
   // do stuff with pagecounter , which is initial count

},[])
```

useEffect also runs on first render,avoid running this on initial render like

```
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0)
    useEffect(()=> {
     if (pageCount===0){
       //this prevent to run on first render
       return 
     }
     // code here will only run on updating state
    },[pageCount])
```

Comment: Hi Vamshi, I have updated the post trying to use this method instead of my function "updateTitles()". But I get an error saying Maximum Update Depth Exceeded

Comment: break useEffect() initial by checking like in updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Options() {
  // Component States
  const [pageCounter, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [optionTitles, setOptionTitles] = useState({
    Option1: "End of Lease Clean",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  });
  //Component Variables
  const pageOneTitles = {
    Option1: "End of Lease Clean",
    Option2: "Regular House Cleaning",
    Option3: "Other Clean"
  };
  const pageTwoTitles = {
    Option1: "Blah1",
    Option2: "Blah12",
    Option3: "Blah13"
  };
  const pageThreeTitles = {
    Option1: "MrMagoo",
    Option2: "Nins",
    Option3: "Pottao"
  };

  function updateTitles() {
    switch (pageCounter) {
      case 1:
        setOptionTitles(pageOneTitles);
        break;
      case 2:
        setOptionTitles(pageTwoTitles);
        break;
      case 3:
        setOptionTitles(pageThreeTitles);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default");
        break;
    }
  }

  function nextPage() {
    if (pageCounter < 3) {
      setPage(prev => prev + 1, updateTitles());
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function prevPage() {
    if (pageCounter > 1) {
      setPage(pageCounter - 1, updateTitles());
      console.log(pageCounter);
    }
  }

  function printLog() {
    console.log(pageCounter);
  }

  return (
    <div id="options">
      <button onClick={() => prevPage() } } id="next">
        Back
      </button>
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option1} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option2} />
      <CardOption title={optionTitles.Option3} />
      <p>{}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { nextPage() }} id="next">
        Next
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => { printLog() }} id="next">
        log
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
function CardOption(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h2>{props.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Options;
```

The `onClick` should pass a callback to call the function instead of calling it.
Also I don't see you using `useEffect` in the code your snippet

Comment: currently onClick is fine. functions aren't getiing called.
```
onClick={goBack}
```
is equal to `onClick={() => goBack()}`.
I think what you mean is 
`onClick={goback()} //  this is wrong`

Comment: here's link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-event-pointers-x9yho

Answer (score 0):

Combine `useEffect()` with `useCallback()` function.

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    updateTitles();

 },[pageCounter]);

  const updateTitles = useCallback(() => {
    switch (pageCounter) {
      case 1:
        setOptionTitles(pageOneTitles);
        break;
      case 2:
        setOptionTitles(pageTwoTitles);
        break;
      case 3:
        setOptionTitles(pageThreeTitles);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default");
        break;
    }
  }, [pageCounter]);
```

Delete `updateTitles()` function from `nextPage()` and `prevPage()`